# Does Rimefire plate armor grant resist 1 to all damage?

Tags: dnd-4e

My character just got hold of a Summoned Rimefire Plate Armor +2.

Am I reading it right in that it seems to grant `Resist 1` to all damage?

Or am I misreading/misunderstanding what it means?

[image: Rimefire Armor]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**

Rules Compendium p224

> Resistance appears in a stat block or powers as "Resist *x*", where *x* is the amount that the damage is reduced, followed by the type of damage that is being resisted.

So "Resist 1 all" is exactly what you think it is, reduce all damage taken by 1 point.